# Dynamically update tooltip when hovering in chart.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

In the example below If im hovering between 40 and 50 the tooltip should move there, outputting 40.5, it should constantly update depending on where my mouse is.

Would it also be possible to show a `ball shape` on the line, indicating where im hovering?

[image: img]

What is needed to achieve this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Banks , that would defeat the purpose of the tooltip showing precisely where it should be showing . No ?

Comment: Even though that might be the case, I still would rather get a rough estimate of the tooltips position even though it might not be accurate.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453714/move-tooltip-further-from-data-point-for-chart-js